# Disable the message shown when a node is created

Tags: nodes

I'm using Rules to redirect the user to a different page after a node has been created.

Is there an easy way to suppress the sticky "XXXXX has been created" message?

Comment: The only way I can think of is using a custom module. Would that be a solution for your case, if nothing else is available?

Comment: I have a custom module that disables some fields only meant for admin users but I basically want the content type to behave like a normal form submission.

Answer (score 3):

It's node_form_submit that is creating those messages. You could pretty easily use hook_form_alter on the node form and use your own version of node_form_submit instead. All you would need to do, would be to copy the function and add an user_access('whatever') check before that message is created.

Alternatively, you could in preprocess_page function, check which messages is being served, and remove unwanted ones, but that would be a bit more tricky. Should be possible with some regex. On the other hand, this method would be a bit more upgrade friendly, since you could remain using the node_form_submit function and would get future changes if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Disable Messages](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) drupal module to hide specific messages from users

Answer (score 0):

If you're using D6 you can use [Better Messages](http://drupal.org/project/better_messages) module.